# Sharing internet connection from one WLAN adapter to another

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ics

I have a windows 7 PC with two wireless adapters. one should receive the internet connection and one should share it to other computers in its (different) wlan.

the first problem that happens, that as soon as i plug in the second network adapter, the internet connection doesnt work anymore on the first one. maybe because windows is trying to find the internet on the second network (which actually doesnt have any) ?

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
2. Identify the adapter that is actually connected to Internet - Lets call it Adapter#1
3. Identify the adapter that is connected to other computer - Lets call it Adapter#2
4. Right Click on Adapter#1 and go to PROPERTIES -> Sharing -> Put Check Mark on First Box "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection"
5. Select Adapter#2 under "Home Networking Connection"

Your computer will give 192.168.137.1 IP address to Adapter#2 (((Adapter#2 must have "Obtain IP Address Automatically" settings))) so any device connected to Adapter#2 should have IP 192.168.137.***.

Let me know the result...!!!